# Can we add to an Assembla project a tool to allow users to vote for future features?

Tags: project-management, assembla, ticket-system, agile-project-management

In Admin/Tools/More I found the Sopport tool. It is its description:

> The Support tool integrates with the Ticket tool to provide customers
>   a support ticket system for submitting and following issues, bugs, and
>   feature requests. Customers get a personal view of the tickets that
>   they submit.

Unfortunately, I don't see that users can vote up/down the features (or bugs) they prefer. Is it possible to do it with Assembla or we must use an external tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool in Assembla for directly voting on features.  You are looking for a tool such as [Uservoice](https://www.uservoice.com/) - which you could then embed in a custom tab in your Assembla project.

Comment: If I understood you well, Assembla allows to embed any other website to show it in a tab. Could you add a link with the explanation to do it?

Comment: Go to Admin->tools and install a custom tab, the settings are pretty self-explanatory - here is a blog post from when I used to work there (I no longer do): http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/98543/A-Developer-Dashboard-for-All-Your-Tools.aspx